# How to change the program to enter the data with spaces while using fstream

Tags: c++

```
void Motherboards::add()
{
char x;
int X;
fstream InFileMB("Motherboard_List.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::app);
if (!InFileMB)
{
    cerr << "Error: Opening File Failed !!";
}
else
{
MotherBoardEntry:
    system("cls");
    cout << " Enter the name of the Manufacturer :\n";
    string MB__Name_Manufacturer;
    cin >> MB__Name_Manufacturer;

    cout << " Enter Chipset Type :\n";
    string MB_Chip;
    cin >> MB_Chip;

    cout << "Enter Name of the board exactly as it`s written on the box :\n";
    string MB_Name;
    cin >> MB_Name;

    cout << "Enter 3 features of this board :\n";
    cout << "1.) ";
    string MB_Feature1;
    cin >> MB_Feature1;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "2.) ";
    string MB_Feature2;
    cin >> MB_Feature2;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "3.) ";
    string MB_Feature3;
    cin >> MB_Feature3;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Enter Price :\n";
    string MB_Price;
    cin >> MB_Price;

    system("cls");
    cout << "Please check the details before conformation :\n";
    cout << "Motherboard :\n";
    cout << MB__Name_Manufacturer << endl;
    cout << MB_Chip << endl;
    cout << MB_Name << endl;
    cout << "Features :\n";
    cout << "1.) " << MB_Feature1 << endl;
    cout << "2.) " << MB_Feature2 << endl;
    cout << "3.) " << MB_Feature3 << endl;
    cout << "Price :\n";
    cout << MB_Price;
    cout << "\n\n Do You Want To Add The Following Motherboard To Your Stock List ? (y/n)";
    cin >> x;
    system("cls");

    switch (x)
    {
    case 'y':
        InFileMB << "Motherboard :\n" << MB__Name_Manufacturer << endl << MB_Chip << endl << MB_Name << endl << "Price :\n" << MB_Price << endl << "Features :\n" << "1.) " << MB_Feature1 << endl << "2.) " << MB_Feature2 << endl << "3.) " << MB_Feature3 << endl << endl;
        break;

    case 'Y':
        InFileMB << "Motherboard :\n" << MB__Name_Manufacturer << endl << MB_Chip << endl << MB_Name << endl << "Price :\n" << MB_Price << endl << "Features :\n" << "1.) " << MB_Feature1 << endl << "2.) " << MB_Feature2 << endl << "3.) " << MB_Feature3 << endl << endl;
        break;

    case 'n':
        system("cls");
        system("pause,2");
        cout << " Enter ( 1 ) to try to enter the data again or ( 2 ) to go back to item selection list .. ";
        cin >> X;
        switch (X)
        {
        case 1:
            goto MotherBoardEntry;
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        }
        break;

    case 'N':
        system("cls");
        system("pause,2");
        cout << " Enter ( 1 ) to try enter the data again or ( 2 ) to go back to item selection list .. ";
        cin >> X;
        switch (X)
        {
        case 1:
            goto MotherBoardEntry;
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        }

        break;
    }

}

 }
```

When I input the data as I am going to show in the snapshots that I provide when I enter the data without any spaces all goes well but when i do enter the data with spaces i cant fill out certain data due to some reason that I don't know as I am a beginner. Can you please tell me exactly where to update and what to update.

[enter image description here][1]
[enter image description here][2]

As you may have noticed in the picture where i have put a space between i7 and 4790k i couldn`t fill out the information for entering the name of the processor and the command window shifted me directly to the next line.

Comment: [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Comment: What would be the syntax ?  Like std::getline(MB_Chip) is this what i should write ? And if so do i need to make changes for those cout statements as well ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to change the output. The comment above is a link to a reference, which will show the necessary syntax.

Comment: It doesn`t seem to work for me .

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/47Ohy.png